# Assigning same function to multiple values

Tags: javascript

The #Button1 works when I click it but #Button2 does not. If I change the order of them then 2 works but 1 doesn't. Can you not set the same function to multiple events? How would I make this work. Both buttons are on different html pages if that makes a difference.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#Button1').onclick = fun;
    document.querySelector('#Button2').onclick = fun;
});

function fun() {
    alert();
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console saying that something is undefined?

Comment: If buttons are on different pages how is it supposed to find a button that does not exist? The error in the console should clearly state that. You can not add an event to something that does not exist so it throws an error.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, but we can't see your html, so it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Both buttons work: https://jsfiddle.net/hsa5f0uv/1/

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: If Button 2 is on a different page, but the code can't find Button 1, it will throw an error before it gets to button 2.

Comment: Also, why are you combining the use of `.addEventListener()` (the modern standards-based way to set up events) and `onclick` (a less robust and older way)?

Comment: And, if you place your `<script>` just prior to the closing `body` tag, there won't be a need for the `DOMContentLoaded` event and you can just set up the `click` events for the two buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if(document.querySelector('#Button1'))
        document.querySelector('#Button1').onclick = fun;
    if(document.querySelector('#Button2'))
        document.querySelector('#Button2').onclick = fun;
});
```

Comment: Because you haven't actually answered the question. Since we don't have the OPs HTML, we don't have the full picture of what the problem is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the answer, I don't know whether the downvote was yours or whether you're speculating but as far as I can tell, my answer makes the same assumptions as epascarello's and if theirs succeeds mine likely will too; yet their answer has not attracted any downvotes. Perhaps it is another reason?

Comment: Well, you've also just posted code without any explanation, just "Try:", which is not a good answer. You should take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks it worked but I don't really know why my original code didn't.

Comment: @javascriptquestion12344732 it sounds like you only have one of the buttons on each page. When `document.querySelector('#Button1').onclick = fun;` runs and it doesn't find Button1 it causes an error which stops the execution of the rest of the function so `document.querySelector('#Button2').onclick = fun;` never runs. By checking that the element exists you prevent the error from occuring and the code can execute `document.querySelector('#Button2').onclick = fun;`. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to attach an event to something that does not exist. So of course it will throw an error. Looking at the developer console you would see an error message. `VM1455:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')`

If only one element exist you can make one selector that targets both

```
document.querySelector('#Button1, #Button2').addEventListener("click", fun);
```

or use a common class on the buttons

```
document.querySelector('.myFunButton').addEventListener("click", fun);
```

Or you can check to see if the element exists.

```
document.querySelector('#Button1')?.addEventListener('click', fun);
document.querySelector('#Button2')?.addEventListener('click', fun);
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.myFunButton').addEventListener("click", fun);` will only work on the first matching element, not all matches.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, but the OP said the buttons are on different pages. So there is only one button there.